# Can't acces images on Apache HTTP sever on Linux

Tags: linux, apache, httpd.conf

The httpd root is default /var/www/html and i have a image in img/generic-logo.svg

The permissions are set to a+x 777 to the image file, yet apache refuses to give access to the file.

Why can't it be simple as installing WAMP on Windows?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The file permissions look wired, but working. There must be some other cause. Can you access / request other files or scripts form that http server? This sounds more like a configuration issue to me...

Comment: The configuration is default.

Comment: That does not really help, does it? What is the "default"?

Comment: And I wonder what thos gots are (`.`) that are trailing your permissions listing in each row. They do not belong there, never seen that...

Comment: Uhm... http://i.imgur.com/NvTzTS1.png

Comment: Ah, it _could_ be that this is the effect of a security configuration in your setup, that php refuses to read executable files. As mentioned above the permissions you gave to that image are wired anyway, you do not need execution rights in an image file, obviously. So try reducing the permissions to rw-r--r-- or similar. Important is that the http server process can _read_ the file. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Also it _always_ is a very good idea to take a look at your http servers error log file, that is where php logs errors to normally. You might find additional information there.